# Is it safe to assume the performance difference between implicit and explicit print is related to object size?

Tags: r

I've written a couple of methods to produce a network type object with options to define the relationships with a formula or with a list of models.  When trying to invoke my print method, I'm seeing radically different speeds between the objects generated by a list and those generated by a formula

```
setRepositories(ind=1:2)
#* Requires that you have JAGS installed
devtools::install_github("nutterb/HydeNet", ref="devel-brom")
library(HydeNet)

data(PE, package='HydeNet')

#* Object based on a formula 
autoNet <- HydeNetwork(~ wells
                       + pe | wells
                       + d.dimer | pregnant*pe
                       + angio | pe
                       + treat | d.dimer*angio
                       + death | pe*treat,
                       data = PE)

#* Object based on a list of models
g1 <- lm(wells ~ 1, data=PE)
g2 <- glm(pe ~ wells, data=PE, family="binomial")
g3 <- lm(d.dimer ~ pe + pregnant, data=PE)
g4 <- xtabs(~ pregnant, data=PE)
g5 <- glm(angio ~ pe, data=PE, family="binomial")
g6 <- glm(treat ~ d.dimer + angio, data=PE, family="binomial")
g7 <- glm(death ~ pe + treat, data=PE, family="binomial")

bagOfModels <- list(g1,g2,g3,g4,g5,g6,g7)
bagNet <- HydeNetwork(bagOfModels)
```

The `PE` data set that these objects are based on is fairly large itself, and in the list version of the network (`bagNet`), `PE` is carried in all seven of the model objects.  This certainly balloons the size:

```
> object.size(autoNet)
397344 bytes
> object.size(bagNet)
26969592 bytes
```

Now when I try to print the objects, the time it takes to execute the print varies greatly. (I'm aware of `system.time`, but it wasn't showing the execution time for implicit print, so I'm using the ugly work around, sorry)

```
#* time to print autoNet
> a <- Sys.time()
> autoNet
> b <- Sys.time()
> b-a
Time difference of 0.172601 secs

#* Time to print bagNet
> a <- Sys.time()
> bagNet
> b <- Sys.time()
> b-a
Time difference of 33.53736 secs

#* Time to print bagNet explicitly
> a <- Sys.time()
> print(bagNet)
> b <- Sys.time()
> b-a
Time difference of 0 secs
```

There is a [brief discussion](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Huge-performance-difference-between-implicit-and-explicit-print-td4679400.html) at R-devel about it, but it doesn't quite go so far as to say that it is the size of the object that is slowing down the printing.  Am I correct in my assumption?  I'm just wondering if I should recommend using explicit printing in my package documentation.

Comment: In fact it says just the opposite: that a call to `print` is 10x faster than just typing the object name at the console for the same sized object. I was not convinced that overhead of determining what class the object was would explain it. If @Hadley cannot figure it out, then I doubt most people here will be able to answer it. (One of those responses was mildly amusing in chiding Hadley for use of `df` as an object name. I share that as a pet peeve, but I've pretty much given up reminding people.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but only in the current R release, not in R-devel, which will be released as R 3.2.0 in April.  Until recently the implementation of auto-printing was done in a way that caused the object to be duplicated when printing was handled via method dispatch. That has now ben addressed.