# R: Does the use of the print function inside a for loop slow down R

Tags: r

In R, inside a for loop, I am using the function print to display on the Rstudio console the iteration of the for loop. Will this slow down my code or not?

Based on experience I would say that yes but I have no rationale behind that.
Thanks,

Comment: My suggestion is, test and measure it... anyway from my experience, heavy printing (obviously) slows down the execution, and in particular in RStudio I found some problem when the console is full of printed text

Comment: You could consider `print`ing in steps instead of each iteration -- i.e. `if((i %% step) == 0) print()` to avoid multiple calls to `print` which is, also, a function and -depending on the method dispatched- can be time consuming.

Comment: Every function call takes time and `printing` is a rather expensive function call. However, often this additional time is not relevant, because if you feel the need to show progress you either have written extremely inefficient code anyway (i.e., you should be using vectorized functions or a different algorithm) or you do something that is necessarily so slow that the small additional time for printing is negligible in comparison.

Answer (score 6):

It will almost certainly slow down your code, but by how much is the question. If you are printing small objects, such as integers, you probably won't notice much impact. If you print large dataframes, it could be very noticeable.

If you really must print, try to use the appropriate method. For example, use `print.data.frame` instead of just `print`.

My experience has been that printing in a loop is usually only necessary when I want to output plots or tables to a document. Otherwise, it usually only has value for observing and diagnosing issues that may occur in your loop.

See also
[Is it safe to assume the performance difference between implicit and explicit print is related to object size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29245818/is-it-safe-to-assume-the-performance-difference-between-implicit-and-explicit-pr)

Comment: I would use `message` instead of `print` to display the iteration. In fact, when developing codes for others this is recommended since you can use `suppressMessages` then.

Answer (score 3):

it has a great impact on the speed of execution

for example i was training a machine learning model in octave 8th gen i5 intel processor 8gb ram
with print inside loop the speed was 76 training examples per second
but after removing print statement it became 1000 training examples per second

for one loop there was 14000 examples
it really saves huge time!!!!!